# Python: Error 13 Permission denied when using shutil.copy but no error for shutil.move

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, shutil

I am trying to copy all files and folders from one directory to another. If I run the following, it works fine with no error:

```
import shutil

input_path = r'C:\Documents\Input'
output_path = r'C:\Documents\Output'

shutil.move(input_path, output_path)
```

This would be fine, except that I aim to keep the files in the input path as well. When I run `shutil.copy(input_path, output_path)`, I end up getting `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Documents\Input'`. Does anyone know why this might be? It seems odd that the .move works fine while the .copy gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-45-f4c01659b2b9>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.copy(input_path, output_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Documents\Input'
```

Comment: What's the full traceback?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: `copy` may have to open for reading, `move` may use system function and it doen't have to open for reading.

Comment: using `shutil.__file__` you can find source code and you will see it uses `os.rename()` to move file - and as I know it may use `C/C++` code for `rename` which may use system function for moving files.

Comment: Is there any easier way to copy a files over, perhaps not using ```shutil```?